# InputMethodManagerService: Session failed to close due to remote exception

Tags: android, crash

When i type text in auto complete text view automatically keyboard close and then activity also close in kitkat. I am getting error by using this,when i remove this i am not getting any error.But i want custom font for my dropdown list.

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamSSm-XLight.otf");
holder.name.setTypeface(tf);

> InputMethodManagerService: Session failed to close due to remote
>   exception
>                                                                 android.os.DeadObjectException
>                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:403)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1357)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1369)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1389)
>                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1136)
>                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1150)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1315) 02-12
>   22:52:28.926 26181-26196/?
>
> W/InputMethodManagerService: Session failed to close due to remote
>   exception
>                                                                 android.os.DeadObjectException
>                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:403)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1357)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1373)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1389)
>                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1136)
>                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1150)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1315)

Comment: Add the logs above DeadObjectException. Reason for deadobjectexception is in nearby logs.

Comment: when i give  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamSSm-XLight.otf");holder.name.setTypeface(tf); android.os.DeadObjectException

Comment: Can you give complete logs. This will not let you know the reason. As I told you earlier you need to check nearby logs where deadojectexception came to know the real reason.  Provide me the nearby logs.

Comment: above i have attached the full log.

Comment: the reason is        public class Lightbuttontext extends Button {


    public Lightbuttontext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public Lightbuttontext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Lightbuttontext(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/GothamSSm-Light.otf");
        setTypeface(tf ,1);

    }

}

Comment: here i have remove the init method and directly write    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/GothamSSm-Light.otf");
        setTypeface(tf ,1);    this instead of init() method

Comment: If the problem was resolved, can you please write it as an answer? The formatting in comments is not so good.

Comment: Did you find the answer? If yes then can you post it here?